# Recover type of generic collection given as template

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on a generic class that essentially works like that

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Collection>
class myClass
{
  T attr1, attr2, attr3; //Attributes are actually stored in multiple list-like nodes
public:
  void method1(Collection<T> arg)
  {
    attr1 = arg[0];
    attr2 = arg[1];
    attr3 = arg[2];
  }
};
```

For those who know, I am basically trying to create a generic Ternary Search Trie

I've been wondering if there was a way for me to simply write my class so that I can call it like that `myClass<vector<int>>` (for example) and have my attributes be ints and my method argument be my vector of ints ?

Comment: What is this line supposed to mean `T attr1, attr2, attr3,...;`? A vectors size can change at runtime, the number of members of a type not.

Comment: I'll change it. It may create more questions than the question itself and is not really necessary to understand my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways.

If your intention is to use standard containers, you can count on the `value_type` member type.

So, I suppose something as

```
template<typename C>
class myClass
{
  using my_type = typename C::value_type;

  my_type attr1, attr2, attr3;

  public:
  
  void method1 (C arg)
  {
    attr1 = arg[0];
    attr2 = arg[1];
    attr3 = arg[2];
  }
};
```

Otherwise, you can use template specialization

```
template <typename>
class myClass;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename ... Ts>
class myClass<C<T, Ts...>>
{    
  T attr1, attr2, attr3;

  public:
  
  void method1 (C<T, Ts...> arg)
  {
    attr1 = arg[0];
    attr2 = arg[1];
    attr3 = arg[2];
  }
};
```

Unfortunately the last specialization works only for template containers with template type parameters only, so not for `std::array` that receive a non-type template parameter.

For `std::array` you can add another specialization

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Dim>
class myClass<std::array<T, Dim>>
 {
   // ...
 };
```

but this add redundancies, I suppose.

Comment: I suppose the first option also works if I create my other container-classes with ```template<typename value_type>``` ?

Comment: @AnthoJack - Do you mean if you define (through `typedef` or `using`) a `value_type` type member inside your containers? Yes, should works.